# What happens to sharedpreferences when the app is uninstalled?

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I save a `boolean` flag in `sharedpreferences` which I need to get at the very start of app. What happens if I uninstall, install the app again and then get the flag? For me, it doesn't throw an exception and instead sends me the value before uninstalling. I wonder how is that possible..

Comment: I don't understand because SharedPreference is application specific, the storage have to be in the folders of the app. After uninstall/clear, saved datas have to disappear as you can see [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/shared-preferences-how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-554d08671ae9)

Comment: On my app, I loose all saved data on uninstall/reinstall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In android there is a property called `allowBackup`. I think by default it is true. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup). Also for iOS, this package uses `NSUserDefaults` and that is also backed up to iCloud.

Comment: Is there a way to `disable` it on flutter?

Comment: Not via flutter. You'll have to edit the android Manifest and add the the application tag `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"`.

Comment: How can we do the same in iOS as we do in ```android:allowBackup = "false"``` ?

Comment: @RiddhiShah Have you found any solutions? I'm facing a similar issue.